# Python Grocery Program - How to get each item multiplied by its quantity separately?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a program that Create a grocery list of items
  determines the quantity of each item, calculate the subtotal of all of the items on your grocery list, Calculate the total, including a 7% sales tax
and print the sub total and total cost but my program is multiplying the total price by the total quantity instead of multiplying by item.

This is my code

```
item_num = int(input("Please enter the number of items on your grocery  list.\n"))
item_list = [str(input("What is the item #" + str(count + 1) + " on your list?\n")) for count in range(item_num)]
item_price = sum(int(input("Enter the price of the item \n")) for i in range(item_num))
item_quan = sum(int(input("What is the quantity of item #" + str(count + 1) + " that you bought?\n")) for count in range(item_num))
subtotal = sum(int(item_price * item_quan)for i in range(item_num))
print ("The subtotal is...")
print (subtotal)
tax = 0.07 * item_quan
total = subtotal + tax
print ("The grand total is...")
print (total)
```

This is my results after ive ran it.

```
Please enter the number of items on your grocery list.
2
What is the item #1 on your list?
Bike
What is the item #2 on your list?
Gloves
Enter the price of the item 
100
Enter the price of the item 
15
What is the quantity of item #1 that you bought?
2
What is the quantity of item #2 that you bought?
1
The subtotal is...
345
The grand total is...
345.21
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: your tax should just be `tax = 0.07 * subtotal`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's a fixed version:

```
item_num = int(input("Please enter the number of items on your grocery  list.\n"))
item_list = [str(input("What is the item #" + str(count + 1) + " on your list?\n")) for count in range(item_num)]
item_price = [int(input("Enter the price of the item \n")) for i in range(item_num)]
item_quan = [int(input("What is the quantity of item #" + str(count + 1) + " that you bought?\n")) for count in range(item_num)]
subtotal = sum(int(quan * price) for quan, price in zip(item_quan, item_price))
print ("The subtotal is...")
print (subtotal)
tax = 0.07 * subtotal
total = subtotal + tax
print ("The grand total is...")
print (total)
```

Instead of summing the `item_price` and `item_quan` you need to create 2 lists which will contain each item's appropriate price and quantity.

I believe the solution can be made prettier but I wished to change the least amount of code and not rewrite yours.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi @j_mick, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is quite simple: *you're not calculating the individual item prices or quantities in `item_price` or `item_quan`, you're calculating their sum*.

Specifically, in

```
item_price = sum(int(input("Enter the price of the item \n")) for i in range(item_num))
```

and

```
item_quan = sum(int(input("What is the quantity of item #" + str(count + 1) + " that you bought?\n")) for count in range(item_num))
```

you've first created a generator expression (to be hand-wavy, you've created a list), converted every input to an `int` and then called `sum` on the total list. `sum` takes a list and returns a single number. But you don't want the single number (which is the sum of all the items in the list) - you just want an array of corresponding prices and quantities for each item.

Simply remove the `sum` call. It is entirely unnecessary. The only place it should be in is in `subtotal`.

---

More generally, this code sample is not exactly very clean, hence probably why the confusion has set in. I would highly encourage asking for help on improving it at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). For instance, you have multiple duplicate `int` calls everywhere, which are entirely extraneous - the products of two `ints` are also `ints`, so there's no need to convert it to an `int`.

Specifically, however, I want to recommend a slightly nicer of approaching things than the approach you've considered. This is by making use of the `map` and `lambda` functions.

`map` is exactly what it sounds like: it creates a new array whose elements are computed by applying a function to each element in the old array.

`lambda` lets you create a function on the spot (more correctly, it creates an anonymous function, but let's not bog you down with details).

```
item_price = map(lambda item: int(input("Enter the price for this item: {0}".format(item)), item_list]
```

A similar approach will work wonders for `item_quan`. Notice how much easier it is to read and how you don't need to depend on crude constructs like ranges. Thinking in terms of maps also makes it much more obvious what's happening.

Again, please consider using Code Review. It is an excellent tool and will teach you how to write neat and clear code, not just something that works. :)